# Deriving algebraic expression of a phasor

Tags: geometry

Within the electrical power distribution domain there are items referred to as AutoTransformerRectifierUnits (ATRU) and their job is to phase shift incoming AC voltages.

Aspects of this can be solved via "simple" geometry and that is where I am stuck

[image]

One example is the balanced Delta ATRU (source in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUZPN.png) if interested).

As mentioned this is a geometric question not an electrical and the query is associated with deriving the algebraic equations for the shorter two branches.

[image]

If one limb is isolated and it is known that

1. The two major vectors are of equal length
2. The desired angular separation is $20^\circ$

how are the magnitudes of "a" and "b" derived?

I know that the end equation is:

$$ a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}[\sin(20^\circ) - \frac{1 - \cos(20^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)} \cdot \cos(60^\circ) ]$$

$$ b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}[ \frac{1 - \cos(20^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)} ]$$

I am so far struggling to capture this.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUZPN.png) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S100093611830102X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with $b$. Just extend $a$ until it reaches the vertical line. The vertical component of $b$ is $1-1\cdot\cos 20^\circ$. In the small right angle triangle that it's formed, you have $$\sin 60^\circ=\cos 30^\circ=\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}b$$
Therefore $$b=\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}{\sin 60^\circ}$$
Then the horizontal component of $b$ is $b\sin 30^\circ$. In the bigh right angle triangle with $1$ as hypotenuse, you get $$\sin 20^\circ=\frac{a+b\sin 30^\circ}1$$ So $$a=\sin20^\circ-b\sin 30^\circ=\sin20^\circ-\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}{\sin 60^\circ}\sin 30^\circ=\sin20^\circ-\frac{1-\cos20^\circ}{\sin 60^\circ}\cos 60^\circ$$
Notice that there is a factor of $\frac 1{\sqrt3}$ in both terms, which means that the length of the long side is not $1$.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that could be the missing link. It is interesting that you are not seeing a 1/sqrt(3) This will be the relationship between phase and line-line (basically Va - Vb  = sqrt(3)Va from the 1st figure). I wonder if the equations have been derived working from line voltage and not phase (industrial vs aerospace) and thus knowing how they are derived is key in ensuring the correct equation is used. Basically in papers a number is just cited (a=0.177, b=0.040) and is constantly used in 99% of papers. I will used what you have posted and complete the derivation to confirm.

Comment: Thankyou, simple geometry but I just couldn't see it. I agree the1/sqrt(3) is lacking and extending what you have providing with some additional parts of a full ATRU I believe this 1/(sqrt3) has carried on due to a slight oversight in a few designs. Luckily what really matters is "turns ratio" and "a", "b" and "c" (additional aspect) are all numerically   0.577 smaller, basically factors out in the end. Thanks again